# Hosting laravel framework using Plesk

Tags: laravel, hosting, plesk

I am new to laravel framework and have finished the developing part. Now i want to publish my system using Plesk hosting.I have refered a website such as https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000399513-How-to-install-Laravel-application-on-Plesk-server- but i encountered a problem.

On the second step, the "Access to the server over SSH" option is fixed to "Login Prohibited" and i cannot change it.

Is there any other alternatives to do this or any free web hosting suggestion?

Comment: Plesk administrator will be able to grant you permission to access the shell.

Comment: I am the admin but the option to grant permission is nowhere to be found. Please help me cause this is all new to me

Comment: From a terminal or using any ssh client try to ssh into the Plesk server with the username and password that you created as per the instruction from Plesk. If you're not able to login, then I would suggest there is a configuration issue with the SSH on your plesk server

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what your meant @BogdanStoica. Does it mean that this is a configuration issue?

Comment: You might need to take a look over this link and see if that's the case:
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213370009-How-to-give-limited-SSH-access-to-Plesk-domain-s-system-user

Comment: Do i need to contact the administrator and ask them to grant me the access? Anyway thanks @BogdanStoica for your help.

Comment: You were previously saying that you are the admin... Do you have admin rights in Plesk or not? Sorry but it's not clear to me at this point

Comment: what i meant is the main administrator of Plesk. I am a little bit confused. Sorry